# Lua SWIG Basics

Tags: c++, lua, scripting, swig

Im trying to implement basic vector class manipulation using the instructions provided at:

http://swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_adding_member_functions

And I have the following .i:

```
%module mymodule
%{
    typedef struct
    {
        float x,y,z;
    } Vector3f;
%}

typedef struct
{
    float x,y,z;    
} Vector3f;

%extend Vector3f {
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) {
    Vector3f *v;
    v = (Vector3f *) malloc(sizeof(Vector3f));
    v->x = x;
    v->y = y;
    v->z = z;
    return v;
}
~Vector3f() {
    free($self);
}
void print() {
    printf("Vector [%f, %f, %f]\n", $self->x,$self->y,$self->z);
}
};
```

Now my problem is if I call the following code in Lua:

```
print(mymodule)
local v = Vector(3,4,0)
v.print()

--By the way is there an equivalent in Lua?
--del v
```

I got the follow output:

```
table: 0x000001F9356B1920
attempt to call global 'Vector' (a nil value)
```

Obviously the module is loaded properly as I first print the table address
but I cannot create a Vector... I also tried calling the module method like `mymodule:Vector(1,2,3)` still generate an error. What am I missing here?

All I want is to generate a new `Vector` and have the GC destroying it
using the ~Vector3f() method. What should I modify to make this mechanism
working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG will automatically generate a `__gc` metamethod from the destructor.  In principle your class doesn't even need a custom destructor, the default one will do just fine.

Furthermore SWIG does not need to know about all the implementation details of the functions, the signatures are totally sufficient for generating wrapper code.  That is why I have moved the `Vector3f` struct into the literal C++ section (which could also be in a header file) and only repeated the signatures.

Rather than having a `print` member function, why not add capabilities to use `Vector3f` with Lua's `print()` function?  Just write a `__tostring` function which returns a string representation of your object.

**`test.i`**

```
%module mymodule
%{
#include <iostream>

struct Vector3f {
    float x,y,z;
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {
        std::cout << "Constructing vector\n";
    }
    ~Vector3f() {
        std::cout << "Destroying vector\n";
    }
};
%}

%include <std_string.i>

struct Vector3f
{
    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z);
    ~Vector3f();
};

%extend Vector3f {
    std::string __tostring() {
        return std::string{"Vector ["}
            + std::to_string($self->x) + ", "
            + std::to_string($self->y) + ", "
            + std::to_string($self->z) + "]";
    }
};
```

**`test.lua`**

```lua
local mymodule = require("mymodule")
local v = mymodule.Vector3f(3,4,0)
print(v)
```

Example workflow to compile and run:

```
$ swig -lua -c++ test.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/lua5.2/ -fPIC -shared test_wrap.cxx -o mymodule.so -llua5.2
$ lua test.lua
Constructing vector
Vector [3.000000, 4.000000, 0.000000]
Destroying vector
```